# Restrict printer share to specific IP addresses

Tags: 22.04, printing

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I want to share my printer in LAN to specific computers only. But presently if I share printer in LAN it is visible to all the computers in LAN and some people by mistake give command to my printer. Is there any way to allow only specific IP addresses to print on my printer.

Comment: Did you try using `ufw`?

Comment: go to http://127.0.0.1:631/ to share printer